# Trying to make an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

Just trying to make a simple array that takes grades (double variables) and assigns them to the array elements. Also the user determines how many grades they want to assign. It seems simple, yet every time I execute the code, it prints out way too many lines and doesn't stop based on the user input. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;

        Write("How many grades are you wanting to process...");
        num = Read();

        Double[] grades = new Double[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < grades.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("Enter grade:");
            grades[i] = ToDouble(Read());
            WriteLine();
        }
```

It has been a while and feel silly, just came back from python.

Comment: What's the definition of `Read`?

Comment: You asking that simple question lead me to figure out my issue. Apparently Read() returns an Int and I should have been using the ReadLine() to read input. I changed it, and works as intended!!

Comment: By the way, if `Read` returns an int, you cannot enter "6.5" as grade. The "ToDouble" conversion comes too late to fix that. Not sure if that is a problem for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just few modification

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 0;

    Write("How many grades are you wanting to process...");
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Double[] grades = new Double[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter grade:");
        grades[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

> **ReadKey** (returns a character): reads only one single character from
>   the standard input stream. Usually used when you're giving options to
>   the user in the console to select from, such as select A, B or C.
>   Another prominent example, Press Y or n to continue.
>
> **ReadLine** (returns a string): reads only single line from the standard input stream. As an example, it can be used to ask the user
>   enter their name or age.
>
> **Read** (returns an int): reads only one single character from the standard input stream. Similar to ReadKey except that it returns an
>   integer.
>
> This was clearly described with examples in the MSDN documentation
>   (links are included above).

Comment: Thank you! However, I tried parsing Read prior and it gave weird results. Any reason why?